# Camera is not available/detected as DirectShow video capture device

Tags: directshow, video-capture

I try to record video using DirectShow (AMCAP demo), but it shows "Sorry, you have no video capture hardware. Video capture will not function properly".

My camera is Guppy, and I installed [Vimba 1.2.1](http://www.alliedvisiontec.com/us/products/software/vimba-sdk.html). I can get the images using Vimba. The system is Windows 7. I think the driver is installed, but the code cannot find the device.

Can anyone help me about this issue?

```
// enumerate all video capture devices
ICreateDevEnum *pCreateDevEnum=0;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                      IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void**)&pCreateDevEnum);
if(hr != NOERROR)
{
    ErrMsg(TEXT("Error Creating Device Enumerator"));
    return;
}

IEnumMoniker *pEm=0;
hr = pCreateDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEm, 0);
if(hr != NOERROR)
{
    ErrMsg(TEXT("Sorry, you have no video capture hardware.\r\n\r\n")
           TEXT("Video capture will not function properly."));
    goto EnumAudio;
}
```

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus completely off-topic here.

Comment: Vendor's website does not advertise DirectShow compatibility, there is .NET API instead. Or, their driver but be doing something wrong and does not function correctly as DirectShow device.

Comment: @l4mpi: AMCap is Windows SDK sample, the poster might actually have a programming question, but [if this is true] he did not explain himself well enough.

Comment: It is a programming question. I have added some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The camera appears to be not supported via DirectShow. Or, you are expected to configure it appropriately before it appears on the list of devices. The description on the referenced web page suggests that vendor offers product specific SDK rather than integration into Windows API.

This classifies the issue as fitting/compatibility rather than programming question. Contact camera vendor for details.

Comment: In my case, I am using Intex camera which is getting detected in device manger of windows 7  but if I check through graph studio then in `video capture sources` I didn't find any video source. If same camera is connected to any other machine then its getting listed in `video capture sources`. Is there any specific cause of this?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that USB port is working on first machine :)